# Wait untill all permissions are granted

Tags: android, asynchronous, permissions, android-permissions

When start my application I need to check if app have permission to write to device storage and permission to access device location. If don't have app will ask to user these permissions.

For that I use next code:

```
private boolean mayRequestLocations() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and

```
private boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to wait that user to accept first condition (or to close my application) and after the first permission was granted the application to go to next step and ask user to allow to locate device.

I believe that need an AsyncTask but no idea how to do it. Any help please?

Comment: if you want to ask the permission you need to check it in the `onRequestPermissionsResult` using the request code of the permission then if yes, show another dialogue explaining why your app needs to access the location permissions or anything else

Comment: but if all the permissions are mandatory ask them all at once after showing a dialogue

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult look the best solution.